# spark running 10 hrs even after kafka showing 0 message lag

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am running spark streaming and it is consuming message from kafka.I have also defined checkpoint directory in my spark code.

We did a bulk message upload in kafka yesterday. When I check the offset status in kafka using -

```
bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.ConsumerOffsetChecker --group xxx- \
streaming-consumer-group --zookeeper xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2181
```

It shows there is no message lag. However, my spark job is still running for last 10 hrs.

My understanding is spark-streaming code should read the messages sequentially and it should update offset in kafka accordingly.

I am not able to figure out why spark is still running even if there is no message lag in kafka. Can someone explain?

Comment: If you are using direct stream fom kafka, it does not update kafka or zookeeper!!! What does spark UI show? Does spark UI show many active unscheduked batches? Did you enable backpressure in spark?

Comment: If you have the spark ui open, it will keep the spark context open.

Comment: I have to find out what would be ideal backpressure setting. I am reading bulk data from kafka and storing the processed data in mysql [I also have a copy in HDFS using the flume]. I need to do some experiments, its around 3 million rows. Any thoughts on how i should proceed?